# Can Flex AIR apps for Android run as processes?

Tags: android, apache-flex, process, air, android-intent

Is it possible to have an AIR application built in Flex run as process or receive intents?
For example if I wanted to make a calendar and each time there was an event at a certain time, have the AIR up which isn't running in the foreground, pop-up and inform the user that "it's time".

Can it be done with the current stable versions of both AIR and Flex SDK?

Thank you.

I wonder about this still to this day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done with AIR native extensions (ANE). AIR has no built in support for Android intents. 
If you havent heard about native extensions before, have look at this, its interesting:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

You will have to write java Android SDK code. That will pass desired events (intents) to actionscript bridge and your AIR app can handle them as you wish...

Have look here, it might help you with your task
[air native extension - possible to receive broadcast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079754/air-native-extension-possible-to-receive-broadcast)