# air native extension - possible to receive broadcast?

Tags: android, apache-flex, broadcastreceiver, air-native-extension, air-android

I am developing application with Adobe Flex on AIR platform. Using native extension for Android, it is possible to send SMS from my Flex application.

Would it also be possible to receive SMS with my application (receive Broadcast carrying information about incoming SMS)?

More generally, is it possible to receive Android Broadcasts in my Flex application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out this is possible.

> "The native implementation can dispatch events that the ActionScript
>   extension code can listen for. This mechanism  allows the native
>   implementation to perform tasks asynchronously, notifying the
>   ActionScript side when the task is  complete"

Details on how to do it are covered here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/air_extensions.pdf.